# How does bucket versioning affect S3's read-after-write consistency guarantee?

Tags: amazon-s3, eventual-consistency

While S3 supports "read-after-first write" consistency for newly created objects, I wanted to understand how bucket versioning might affect the consistency guarantees—specifically, when accessing a document using a key **and** a version.

Here's my current understanding of the consistency guarantees offered by S3 gathered from official AWS documentation:

```
put (new) then get       = strong (with one caveat; see below)
put (overwrite) then get = eventual
put then list            = eventual
delete                   = eventual
```

Obviously when overwriting an existing object (regardless) of bucket versioning, when I access the object by key alone, I'll get an eventually consistent result. But if I access the object by key and version, what happens? Is there any AWS documentation that point to defined behavior?

My question is highly related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511670/is-creating-a-new-version-of-an-object-in-aws-s3-eventually-consistent-or-read-a) but with one exception: the concept of negative caching from the following caveat. The [AWS docs state](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel) (emphasis mine):

> Amazon S3 provides read-after-write consistency for PUTS of new
>   objects in your S3 bucket in all regions with one caveat. **The caveat
>   is that if you make a HEAD or GET request to the key name (to find if
>   the object exists) before creating the object, Amazon S3 provides
>   eventual consistency for read-after-write.**

When I request an object from S3 located at `key@version` which doesn't exist, I then create/put that object, and immediately following I issue a request for that same `key@version`, what is the behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon S3 will, by default, replace objects when a new object is uploaded with the same filename. When [Amazon S3 versioning](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html) is activated, S3 will retain all versions of a file even when it is overwritten or deleted.

Specific versions of a file are referenced via the combination of Key and Version-Id. In fact, **the Version-Id is assigned as soon as a file is uploaded with versioning turned on**.

When uploading a file with the same file name (thereby creating the latest 'version' of an object), the previous version keeps the Version-Id it was originally assigned.

A sample Version-Id is: `SnZzeMEz3ngtfBYWc53f_Juuzk5epXkG`

Your question asked: *"When I request an object from S3 located at `key@version` which doesn't exist"*. However, given the random nature of the Version-Id, it would not be possible to request a non-existent version of an object and then expect the next upload to create a version with the predicted Version-Id.

Instead, think of it this way: When a version of an object is created, **it keeps the same Version-Id**. Therefore, a version is not being updated so consistency will not be relevant. The only change is that the default "current version" will change, so retrieving the object after having updated the object might be subject to eventual consistency.

Comment: That makes sense. I was under the impression that the version was an incrementing integer value.

Comment: But there is still an interesting point here: When getting by version id after a new version is created. Is this consistent? ... shall I query for that new version id an be sure I will get an anwser. Basically the question is: Does creation of new versions behaves as new object insertions (which has read-after-write consistency)?

Comment: @Rafael, Please start a new Question rather than adding a comment on an old question.